# How to select a specific option based on multiple attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have this select:

```
<select class="required form-control parameter-criteria" selectpicker="" data-id="2" tabindex="-98">
    <optgroup label="criterio 2">
        <option value="1" data-content="<span class=&quot;badge-min filter d-inline-flex&quot; style=&quot;background-color:#ff0000;&quot;> </span>CRITERIO 1 [0 - 50] - CRITERIO 2" id-criteria="2">CRITERIO 1
        </option>
       <option value="2" data-content="<span class=&quot;badge-min filter d-inline-flex&quot; style=&quot;background-color:#ffb700;&quot;> </span>CRITERIO 2 [51 - 60] - CRITERIO 2" id-criteria="2">CRITERIO 2
       </option>
       <option value="3" data-content="<span class=&quot;badge-min filter d-inline-flex&quot; style=&quot;background-color:#66ff00;&quot;> </span>CRITERIO 3 [61 - 100] - CRITERIO 2" id-criteria="2">CRITERIO 3
       </option>
     </optgroup>
</select>
```

I'm trying to select the option which have as `id-criteria=2` and as `value = 3`, so I did:

```
$('.parameter-criteria[data-id=2]')
   .find('option[value=3]')
   .find('id-criteria', 2).prop('selected', true);
```

but this won't work, any idea?

Comment: Did you try this $('.parameter-criteria[data-id=2]').val("3");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify both criteria as `.find('option[value=3][id-criteria=2]')`.

```js
$('.parameter-criteria[data-id=2]')
   .find('option[value=3][id-criteria=2]')
   .prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="required form-control parameter-criteria" selectpicker="" data-id="2" tabindex="-98">
    <optgroup label="criterio 2">
        <option value="1" data-content="<span class=&quot;badge-min filter d-inline-flex&quot; style=&quot;background-color:#ff0000;&quot;> </span>CRITERIO 1 [0 - 50] - CRITERIO 2" id-criteria="2">CRITERIO 1
        </option>
       <option value="2" data-content="<span class=&quot;badge-min filter d-inline-flex&quot; style=&quot;background-color:#ffb700;&quot;> </span>CRITERIO 2 [51 - 60] - CRITERIO 2" id-criteria="2">CRITERIO 2
       </option>
       <option value="3" data-content="<span class=&quot;badge-min filter d-inline-flex&quot; style=&quot;background-color:#66ff00;&quot;> </span>CRITERIO 3 [61 - 100] - CRITERIO 2" id-criteria="2">CRITERIO 3
       </option>
     </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: mm for me this won't work, maybe is because I'm using the selectpicker plugin?

Comment: If DOM is rendered as you posted in question then it should work. You can also check that in browser console.

Comment: oh your code works fine, I forgot to execute .selectpicker('refresh')